# Strong chains in $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ mod finite of length $\omega_3$

Tags: set-theory, forcing, infinite-combinatorics

Probing a bit the difference between $[\omega_1]^{\omega_1}$ and $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ modulo the finite sets:

> **Question**
>
> Can there exist a family $\langle X_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_3\rangle$ of
> sets in $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ such that for $\alpha<\beta<\omega_3$,
>
> - $|X_\beta\setminus X_\alpha|=\omega_2$, and
> - $ X_\alpha\setminus X_\beta$ is finite?

The existence of such a family (a *strong chain of length $\omega_3$ in $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ mod finite*) implies the existence of a strongly almost disjoint family in $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ of size $\omega_3$:  let $A_\alpha:=X_{\alpha+1}\setminus X_\alpha$, and we get a collection of size $\omega_3$ in $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ with pairwise finite intersection.  The existence of such a family is consistent, as shown by Baumgartner [1].

Koszmider [2] showed that you can have long chains (of length $\omega_2$) in $[\omega_1]^{\omega_1}$ modulo the finite ideal, so this question is an attempt to lift his result to $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$.  (I do not even know the answer for $[\omega_2]^{\omega_2}$ if ``finite'' is replaced by countable, but obviously a consistency result there should be easier to obtain, I just don't know if it's been done.)

There are differences between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ that indicate this question may be interesting.  Koszmider [3] showed that one can have a sequence $\langle f_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_2\rangle$ that is strictly increasing mod finite, while Shelah [4] has shown in ZFC that this phenomenon CANNOT happen at $\omega_2$: there is no sequence $\langle f_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_3\rangle$ of functions in $^{\omega_2}\omega_2$ that is strictly increasing mod finite.

[1] *Baumgartner, James E.*, [**Almost-disjoint sets, the dense set problem and the partition calculus**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(76)90018-8), Ann. Math. Logic 9, 401-439 (1976). [ZBL0339.04003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0339.04003).

[2] *Koszmider, Piotr*, [**On the existence of strong chains in $(\wp(\omega_1)/ \text{Fin})$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2586726), J. Symb. Log. 63, No. 3, 1055-1060 (1998). [ZBL0936.03043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0936.03043).

[3] *Koszmider, Piotr*, [**On strong chains of uncountable functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02803525), Isr. J. Math. 118, 289-315 (2000). [ZBL0961.03039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0961.03039).

[4] *Shelah, Saharon*, [**On long increasing chains modulo flat ideals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.200910010), Math. Log. Q. 56, No. 4, 397-399 (2010). [ZBL1200.03031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1200.03031).

Answer (score 3):

No, there can't. The argument is not too different from Shelah's. I emailed you a note.

Comment: This is similar to the thing from the MEHIFOX notes, right? Only "one cardinal down"?

Comment: The same argument works. If $\kappa$ is any cardinal, there are no strong chains of subsets of $\kappa^{++}$ of length  $\kappa^{+++}$. It was stated then so as to agree with the abstract of Shelah's paper. I think Velickovic also pointed it out there, though I can't say for sure since I wasn't there. In the question as well, the version stated is not per the abstract of the paper of Shelah.

Comment: Right.  Shelah's abstract confused me at first as well since states something about chains of length $\omega_4$ in $^{\omega_3}\omega_3$ mod countable.  Are the MEHIFOX notes available somewhere?

Comment: Is your email address on this webpage the correct one? The MEHIFOX notes are on the ArXiv, but don't have the full proof. I did send an email to that address, but it is possible it got caught in the spam filter etc.. https://www.ohio.edu/cas/eisworth